# How to add .decode("unicode-escape") to all ipython output?

Tags: ipython, python-unicode

Both in python and ipython:

```
In [1]: complex_object = ['test', u'тест']

In [2]: print(complex_object)
['test', u'\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442']

In [3]: complex_object
Out[3]: ['test', u'\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442']

In [4]: print(complex_object[1])
тест

In [5]: complex_object[1]
Out[5]: u'\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442'

In [6]: print(complex_object.__repr__().decode("unicode-escape"))
['test', u'тест']
```

How could I configure ipython to always output variables like this:

```
In [1]: complex_object = ['test', u'тест']

In [2]: complex_object
['test', u'тест']
```

All that I found is:

```
$ grep -n print_method core/formatters.py
216:       :attr:`print_method`. If is does, that object is passed to that method
236:    print_method = ObjectName('__repr__')
...
```

and no more documentation